# What does the second value of `x` mean here?

Tags: derivatives

I looked into this [fun math question](http://www.iflscience.com/editors-blog/math-question-baffled-scottish-teens) and I understood his whole explanation except for one part. When he sets $T'(x)=0$, he eventually concludes to $x=8$ and $x=0$. What does the $x=0$ mean? I understand that $x=8$ is the point on the graph where the slope is zero, which indicates (especially when you graph it and look at it) that this is the minimum that we are looking for. But the point $(0, 110)$ is just a point on the sloped part of the curve. What is the significance of this point?

Comment: Try the second derivative at x=0 and it will tell you that you have a "saddle" point. https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=math+saddle+point

Comment: @Moti Since $T'(0)=-4$ (and $T''(0)=\frac{5}{6}$), $x=0$ is no critical point of $T$ (or $T'$). I'm not sure what you mean by "saddle point"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about 7:30: It's not $x=0$, it's $$x>0.$$

Normally you would have

$$\begin{align}x^2&=64\\\Longrightarrow~~~x&=\pm \sqrt{64}\end{align}$$
but since $x$ is positive (because it's the length of a line segment where, in this context, negative values don't make sense), i.e. $x>0$, he knows that $x=8$ and $x\neq 8$.

Comment: So there is no significance to $x=0$? Another reason wy I'm curious is because when I graphed it at [https://www.desmos.com/calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) they showed the curve and 2 points: $(0, 110)$ and $(8, 98)$. Why would the calculator default to showing what happens at $x=0$? There must be something significant about this point, no?

Comment: Well, the second derivative of $T$ has a global maximum at $x=0$. You could say that it's the point of maximal curvature of the graph of $T$. Other than that (and the obvious fact that this is the minimal value of $x$ that makes sense in the context) I don't see any significance, no.

Comment: @bedspread232 Desmos always highlights the point at $x=0$. It's the $y$-intercept.

Comment: Ah, that explains it then @AkivaWeinberger . Thank you both!